# Printing ID from database

Tags: php, forms

I created a HTML form wich is sending the data to a MYSQL/PHPmyAdmin page through a PHP section. That works fine. Every record in the DB gets a unique field (reparationID)

Based on the ReparationID I want to create a barcode and print it on a management page. Is this possible in PHP?
I have created a big button that must do the action, but i don't know how yet..

Comment: ReparationID i want to create a (bar)code...Dont understand.

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the `ID` from the database or how to create a barcode or... something completely different?

Comment: Check out http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php

Comment: i'm sorry. My question was how can i create a barcode from the ID field of database (auto increment) and print this?

Comment: Repeating the same broad question phrased slightly different doesn’t help. What _exactly_ is the part you are having trouble with? (If it’s just “all of them”, then you might need to go learn some basics first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get id from DB and create 12 digit number with this code :

```
$s_number0 = str_pad( $id, 12, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

this code create 12 digit number

then save this code to DB and create Barcode whith this class :

http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-barcode-generator-class-code-39.htm

Comment: And this number is then unique? or do i need the uniqid for that?

Comment: this id is unique because your db id is unique :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It works when i do it on a empty page, but when i do it in my template, there is a blue question mark. This is my code, wich doesn't work.           [code]  <?php

// include Barcode39 class 
include "Barcode39.php"; 

// set Barcode39 object 
$barcode = new Barcode39("38589293949ggg"); 
?>

<!--display new barcode -->

<div class="barcode">
<?php $barcode->draw(); ?>
</div> [/code]